# Oraclize Queries Not Working On Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles, rinkeby

I have the following contract (https://gist.github.com/postables/365f418b85c9d93503001682d6cc779e) which works when using Oraclize's web IDE version of remix.

However when testing the contract out on Rinkeby, I can't get it to work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but would love some help.